# Updating an newly created object's association inside its block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Rails 5.2.1**

In my user model I have:

```
has_one :profile
before_create :build_profile
```

This works when a user registeres on my website, creating an associated Profile object.

Using seeds.rd and inside:

```
require 'faker'

User.create(email: Faker::Internet.email, password: 'nopassword') do |u|
  u.profile.update_attributes({...})
  # u.create_profile({...}) ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: You cannot call create unless the parent is saved
end
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method update_attributes for nil:NilClass

Is ActiveRecord not being called in the seeds.rb? What works?:

```
[...]

u.build_profile({...})

[...]
```

The issue with this, now, is that I'm having duplicate objects because of `before_create :build_profile`. Removing this line from the user.rb file, all is well. I need not to remove it and still be able to run my seeds.rb without an issue. How to achieve this?

Comment: What about calling ActiveRecords callbacks before_safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about if you update the profile after you create the user?

```
u = User.create(...)
u.profile.update_attributes({...})
```

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L35) for create you'll see that save gets called after the block gets executed, so your `before_create` method won't get called until after the block executes.

If you call `profile.update_attributes` inside the block, it will create a profile before `before_create` runs and then `before_create` will create another one.

If you really want to use the block, you could have a check in your `before_create` method that will only create a profile if one doesn't already exist:

```
before_create :ensure_profile_built

private
def ensure_profile_built
  build_profile unless profile
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Why there is not an option to update the profile object within the user create block?

Comment: Splendid! This is what fits best. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is because the block for create is being called before your object is saved. This means that your callback hasn't yet fired when your block is executed, you can easily check it with:

```
User.create { |u| puts u.persisted? }
```

In order to make it work for you with a block, you can use tap:

```
User.create.tap { |u| u.profile.update_attributes }
```